SSRS Report error - There is no data for the field at position 22
Picture of the exact SPROC failing
Picture of SSRS Data set using the SPROC
Finding the error below when invoking SSRS report. Has anyone resolved this error, or is there a way to determine what field is at position 13? :
See dataset and stored procedure above.
library!ReportServer_0-36!3074!05/01/2024-15:14:00:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/intappopen/conflictsreport_v3')processing!ReportServer_0-36!1e14!05/01/2024-15:14:00:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 13.;
Finding the error below when invoking SSRS report. Has anyone resolved this error, or is there a way to determine what field is at position 13? :
library!ReportServer_0-36!3074!05/01/2024-15:14:00:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/intappopen/conflictsreport_v3')processing!ReportServer_0-36!1e14!05/01/2024-15:14:00:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 13

One common scenario where this can happen is when a dataset is bound to a stored procedure and the result set of the stored procedure does not match the field definitions bound to the dataset at design time, when the query is executed at runtime.
This can happen when stored procedures are coded to optionally or haphazardly return varying shaped result sets, usually by a logical branch, and one of the result sets returned during execution does not match the dataset field definition at runtime.
CREATE PROCEDURE Fubar(@AntiPatternSelection INT)
AS
IF(@AntiPatternSelection = 1 )
   SELECT NUL, NULL, NULL, NULL
ELSE IF(@AntiPatternSelection = 2 )
   SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM SomeTable
ELSE IF(@AntiPatternSelection = 3 )
   SELECT * FROM SomeTable2  

This can generally be treated as a warning unless the underlying change breaks reporting logic.

Thanks for this Ross. I added screenshots of the data set in SSRS, and the stored procedure behind that data set that is failing. Any thoughts on what could be the mismatch between the two?

On the Query tab of your Dataset Properties, do you have a Query type with a value bound to an expression? If you do, does that expression change based on the value of some other report item? Also, are you sure that is the exact version of the SP in all environments in which the report is running in?
